# Which deconvolution algorithm is best suited for removing motion blur from text?

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to process pictures taken with a mobile phone. The pictures contain text, and they have small amounts of motion blur, which I need to remove.

What would be the most viable algorithm to use? I have tested so far Lucy-Richardson and Weiner deconvolution, but they did not yield satisfactory results.

Comment: have you found any effective workable solution to it? or just went with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Motion blur is a difficult problem to overcome. The best results are gained when

1. The speed of the camera relative to the scene is known
2. You have many pictures of the blurred object which you can correlate.

You do have one major advantage in that you are looking at text (which normally constitutes high contrast features). If you only apply deconvolution to high contrast (I know that the theory is often to exclude high contrast) areas of your image you should get results which may enable you to better recognise characters. Also a combination of sharpening/blurring filters pre/post processing may help.

I remember being impressed with [this paper](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/projects/motion_deblurring/index.html) previously. Perhaps an adaption on their implementation would be worth a go.

Answer (score 6):

Agree with @TheJuice, your problem lies in the PSF estimation. Usually to be able to do this from a single frame, several assumptions need to be made about the factors leading to the blur (motion of object, type of motion of the sensor, etc.).

You can find some pointers, especially on the monodimensional case, [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.153.4398&rep=rep1&type=pdf). They use a filtering method that leaves mostly correlation from the blur, discarding spatial correlation of original image, and use this to deduce motion direction and thence the PSF. For small blurs you might be able to consider the motion as constant; otherwise you will have to use a more complex accelerated motion model.

Unfortunately, mobile phone blur is often a compound of CCD integration and non-linear motion (translation perpendicular to line of sight, yaw from wrist motion, and rotation around the wrist), so Yitzhaky and Kopeika's method will probably only yield acceptable results in a minority of cases. I know there are methods to deal with that ("depth awareness" and other) but I have never had occasion of dealing with them.

You can preview the results using photo recovery software such as Focus Magic; while they do not employ YK estimator (motion description is left to you), the remaining workflow is necessarily very similar. If your pictures are amenable to Focus Magic recovery, then *probably* YK method will work. If they are not (or not enough, or not enough of them to be worthwhile), then there's no point even trying to implement it.

Comment: I tried Focus Magic on [one of my test samples](http://i.imgur.com/6Txyq.png), and [this is the output](http://i.imgur.com/No1s0.png). I used for parameters step 6 and 70 degrees, but the output seems actually slightly worse. Do you think that YK could do much better than that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the estimation of your point-spread function is likely to be more important than the algorithm used.  It depends on the kind of motion blur you're trying to remove, linear motion is likely to be the easiest but is unlikely to be the kind you're trying to remove: i imagine it's non-linear caused by hand movement during the exposure.

Comment: Yes, it is non-linear. When people press the camera button, their hand seems to accelerate the camera in practice. So there is definitely a non-linear component.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot eliminate motion blur. The information is lost forever. What you are dealing with is a CCD that is recording multiple real objects to a single pixel, smearing them together. In other words if the pixel reads 56, you cannot magically determine that the actual reading should have been 37 at time 1, and 62 at time 2, and 43 at time 3.

Another way to look at this: imagine you have 5 pictures. You then use photoshop to blend the pictures together, averaging the value of each pixel. Can you now somehow from the blended picture tell what the original 5 pictures were? No, you cannot, because you do not have the information to do that.

Comment: Not true, if you can estimate the point-spread function (PSF) then you can apply a deconvolution algorithm (as the OP states in the title) to enhance the image.

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of "enhance". As a practical matter, you cannot deblur an image in any way that a normal person would regard as a significant improvement. Deconvolution is only relevant from a practical standpoint when you have a known signal transformation. A motion blur is a HIGHLY chaotic function that you will not be able to determine to any degree of usefulness, except in some contrived laboratory example.

Comment: A typical digital image of the real world has a LOT of redundancy, that's why you can recover from many transformations that would mean irreversible information loss when applied to images with maximum entrophy.